# downloading complete web pages (not sites)

Tags: bash, web

I often use offline time (e.g. when on the car/train/plane) to read articles pulled from the web.
To store the content, I currently use Firefox's *Save Page As*.
(Note that's **not** recursively downloading entire websites, but just individual pages plus their styles, images etc.)

I have looked into automating this, but neither wget nor HTTrack give me what I need (it's either too much or too little - or even both).

Any recommendations would be most welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `wget --page-requisites` ?

```
       This option causes Wget to download all the files that are neces‐
       sary to properly display a given HTML page.  This includes such
       things as inlined images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed - though I feel stupid for not having discovered it before...

Answer (score 4):

You should use a firefox extension: ScrapBook
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/427

ScrapBook is a Firefox extension, which helps you to save Web pages and easily manage collections. Key features are lightness, speed, accuracy and multi-language support. Major features are:

- Save Web page
- Save snippet of Web page
- Save Web site
- Organize the collection in the same way as Bookmarks
- Full text search and quick filtering search of the collection
- Editing of the collected Web page
- Text/HTML edit feature resembling Opera's Notes

Comment: Thanks. I had tried ScrapBook, but the data wasn't easily portable across machines/profiles, plus it cannot easily be scripted.

Answer (score 2):

no scripting solution, but I use [Scrapbook](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/427) to archive site for later reading.
Its a wonderfull extension!

Answer (score 1):

If you have an iPhone, then you can use a service called [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/).  It allows you to bookmark pages for reading later (uses a small bookmarklet in your browser).  Once bookmarked, the pages can then be sync'd to your iPhone over the air (Wifi or Cellular) from the Instapaper servers.  Once the app has completed syncing, all the data is stored locally on the iPhone.

As an added bonus, the Instapaper servers process the page and can serve the text-only version of the page (also can do the graphical version) which can be easier for reading.

I use the service and find it excellent for filling in my hour long commute on the train.

Answer (score 0):

Save as a PDF extensions are available for firefox that can help do it too and save some work.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer can save pages as MHTML. Most probably you can automate using this using VBS and COM.