# save web pages while browsing

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [downloading complete web pages (not sites)](https://superuser.com/questions/22191/downloading-complete-web-pages-not-sites)

how to save only the web page i browse to see them later offline and i want to be able to move them and copy to another pc or usb device

thank you,

Comment: superuser.com question

Answer (score 3):

In any browser, press Ctrl+S or go to File -> Save
And then select any folder you wish to save the file in.
And then you can open it without an internet connection :)